# Line() in d3 generating NaN

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Started D3 and JS a week ago. I am trying to plot a Multi-Series Line chart, and I am stuck trying to figure out why line() is returning NaNs. The x domain is discrete string values ["70","71","72".."80"]. Using d3 v4.

I tried tweaking the X-Y scales, range values etc. Tried to identify fracture point and turns out it was the line().

```
var XScale = d3.scaleBand(); 
var YScale = d3.scaleLinear();          
XScale.domain(findata.map(d=>d.values.year)).range([0,width]);`
```

\"findata" is my JS object after importing the data.

```
YScale.domain([
       d3.min(getmaxscale),        //I separately calculate the min-max
       d3.max(getmaxscale)
]).range([height,0]);  

lineGenerator
      .x(function(d){return XScale(d.model) })
      .y(function(d){return YScale(d.avg)});
```

This is what I tried to check the output:

```
var a= findata.map(d=>d.value);

console.log(lineGenerator([a[0].model,a[0].avg]));
```

\testing for a given row.

Output (Incorrect): MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaN

//--------------------------

Sample Data:

```
[
  {
    "Car": "AMC Ambassador Brougham",
    "MPG": "13",
    "Displacement": "360",
    "Horsepower": "175",
    "Weight": "3821",
    "Model": "73",
    "Origin": "US"
  },
  {
    "Car": "AMC Ambassador DPL",
    "MPG": "15",
    "Displacement": "390",
    "Horsepower": "190",
    "Weight": "3850",
    "Model": "70",
    "Origin": "US"
  },
  {
    "Car": "AMC Ambassador SST",
    "MPG": "17",
    "Displacement": "304",
    "Horsepower": "150",
    "Weight": "3672",
    "Model": "72",
    "Origin": "US"
  },
  {
    "Car": "AMC Concord",
    "MPG": "19.4",
    "Displacement": "232",
    "Horsepower": "90",
    "Weight": "3210",
    "Model": "78",
    "Origin": "US"
  },
  {
    "Car": "AMC Concord",
    "MPG": "24.3",
    "Displacement": "151",
    "Horsepower": "90",
    "Weight": "3003",
    "Model": "80",
    "Origin": "US"
  },
  {
    "Car": "AMC Concord d/l",
    "MPG": "18.1",
    "Displacement": "258",
    "Horsepower": "120",
    "Weight": "3410",
    "Model": "78",
    "Origin": "US"
  },
  {
    "Car": "AMC Concord DL",
    "MPG": "23",
    "Displacement": "151",
    "Horsepower": "0",
    "Weight": "3035",
    "Model": "82",
    "Origin": "US"
  },
  {
    "Car": "AMC Concord DL 6",
    "MPG": "20.2",
    "Displacement": "232",
    "Horsepower": "90",
    "Weight": "3265",
    "Model": "79",
    "Origin": "US"
  }
]
```

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>CS590: HW1, Problem 1</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
        .axis--x path {
            display: inline;
            }
        .line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: steelblue;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            //Define the "margins" which will be used to set up the SVG container. 
            var margin = {top: 20, right: 60, bottom: 30, left: 20},
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                        .append("g")    // check g. 
                           .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
            //Set up the axis. 

            //Create a line generator object. 
            var lineGenerator = d3.line().curve(d3.curveBasis);

            //Import data AJAX call: 
            d3.csv("data/old_cars.csv")
                .then(function(data) {

                    //Construct a new data structure. 
                    //
                    //
                    //Getting the data. 
                    function getdata(data){

                    function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
                        return self.indexOf(value) === index;
                    }

                    function getavg(data, country, modelyear){
                        fullarr= [];
                        //fullarr.countryname = country; 
                        //fullarr.model = modelyear
                        sum=0
                        //console.log(data)
                        for(i=0; i<+Object.keys(data).length-2; i++)
                        {   
                            //console.log(data[i]["Origin"])                       
                            if((data[i]["Origin"] == country) && (data[i]["Model"] == modelyear)){
                                fullarr.push({
                                    mpg: +data[i].MPG
                                })
                            }
                        }
                        //console.log(fullarr)
                        for (j=0 ; j <(+Object.keys(fullarr).length); j++){
                            sum=sum+fullarr[j].mpg;
                        }
                        avg = sum/((+Object.keys(fullarr).length)); 
                        //fullarr.avg = avg; 
                        return(avg)
                    } 
                    //fullarr = getavg(data, "US", 70);
                    //console.log(fullarr)
                    let myData = [];
                    myData.values = {};

                    console.log(data);

                    tempdata= [];
                    tempdata.values = {};

                    var countryList = data.map(d => d.Origin).filter(onlyUnique);
                    var yearList = data.map(d => d.Model).filter(onlyUnique).sort();

                    for(m=0; m<countryList.length; m++){
                        tempdata = [];
                        tempdata.values = {};
                        for (l = 0 ; l<yearList.length; l++) {
                            //console.log(yearList[l])
                            tempdata.country = countryList[m];
                            //console.log(tempdata.country)
                            tempdata.values.year = yearList[l];
                            //console.log(tempdata.values.year)
                            a  = getavg(data, countryList[m], yearList[l]);
                            tempdata.values.avg=a;
                            //console.log(tempdata.values.avg)
                            ret = {
                                country: tempdata.country,
                                values : {
                                    year: +tempdata.values.year,
                                    avgval: +tempdata.values.avg
                                }
                            }
                            //console.log(ret)
                            myData.push(ret);
                        }
                    }
                    //console.log(myData);    
                    return myData; 
                    }
                function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
                    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
                }
                var countryList = data.map(d => d.Origin).filter(onlyUnique);

                myData= getdata(data);
                console.log(myData);
                //console.log(countryList.length);
                let findata = [];
                for(p=0; p<countryList.length; p++)
                {   
                    var forthiscity = myData.map(d => d).filter(function(d) {return d.country == countryList[p]});
                    console.log(forthiscity);
                    let newdata = {};

                    newdata = {
                    country: countryList[p],
                    value: {
                        avg: forthiscity.map(d=> +d.values.avgval),
                        model: forthiscity.map(d=> +d.values.year)
                    } }
                    findata.push(newdata);
                    console.log(findata)
                }
                //
                //
                //GOT THE DATA
                //

                //

                var XScale = d3.scaleBand(); 
                var YScale = d3.scaleLinear(); 
                var CScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(); //color scale. 

                XScale.domain(myData.map(d=>d.values.year)).range([0,width])
                //console.log(myData.map(d=>d.values.year).filter(onlyUnique))
                console.log(XScale("74"))

                var getmaxscale = myData.map(d=>d.values.avgval)
                //console.log(d3.max(getmaxscale));

                YScale.domain([
                    d3.min(getmaxscale),
                    d3.max(getmaxscale)
                ]).range([height,0]);

                CScale.domain(countryList).range(["red", "green", "blue"]);

                //Define the X axis. 
                xAxis= d3.axisBottom(XScale);
                yAxis = d3.axisLeft(YScale);

                lineGenerator
                .x(function(d){return XScale(d.model) })
                .y(function(d){return YScale(d.avg)});

                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
                    .attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+"," + height + ")")
                    .call(xAxis)
                .append("text")
                   .attr("x" , width/2)

                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)")
                    .call(yAxis)
                .append("text") 
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("x", margin.left-5)
                .attr("y", -margin.top-20)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .style("fill", "black")
                .text("Average Mileage");

                var ccountry = svg.selectAll(".ccountry")
                    .data(findata)
                    .enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "ccountry");

                var a= findata.map(d=>d.value);
                console.log(a[0])
                console.log(a[0].avg)
                console.log(XScale(a[0].model[12]))
                console.log(lineGenerator([a[0], a[0]]));

                ccountry.append("path")
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", function(d) { return lineGenerator(d.value); })
                .style("stroke", function(d) { return CScale(d.country); });
                /*
                ccountry.append("text")
                //.datum(function(d) { return {id: d.country, value: d.value[d.value.length - 1]}; })
                .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + XScale(d.value.model) + "," + YScale(d.value.avg) + ")"; })
                .attr("x", 3)
                .attr("dy", "0.35em")
                .style("font", "10px sans-serif")
                .text(function(d) { return d.country; });*/
                })  
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Need a bit more info to help debug this issue. It would really help if you count link to a minimal reproducable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. But, could you add to your post what the output of `XScale.domain()` and `YScale.domain()` print out? These should output the data that was used to create these domains, so here we'd just be checking that the scales were set up correctly. Then you might try logging the output of, say, XScale('90') etc, to check in isolation that the scales are mapping your modal as you expect.

Comment: I checked the scales, they are outputting correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to fully test your code, but I think that the problem is the following:

You are defining the line generator as:

```
lineGenerator
  .x(function(d){return XScale(d.model) })
  .y(function(d){return YScale(d.avg)});
```

And then you are calling it this way:

```
lineGenerator([a[0].model,a[0].avg])
```

So when you call the lineGenerator, you are passing `model` and `avg`, and then, the line generator is trying to access to `model` and to `avg` again, so changing the call to:

```
lineGenerator([a[0],a[0]])
```

Might solve the problem

**Edit after seeing the example**

When you do `attr("d", function(d) { return lineGenerator(d.value); })` You are passing the data this way:

```
{
  avg: (7) [15, 17, 13, 18.75, NaN, 24.3, NaN],
  model: (7) [70, 72, 73, 78, 79, 80, 82]
}
```

And the line generator expects the data this way:

```
[
    {avg: 15, model: 70},
    {avg: 17, model: 72},
    {avg: 13, model: 73},
    {avg: 18.75, model: 78},
    {avg: NaN, model: 79},
    {avg: 24.3, model: 80},
    {avg: NaN, model: 82},
]
```

Right before the `ccountry.append("path")` line, I did the following and change the data format (this is just an example, I would change the functions that you are using to format them in the correct way):

```
var lineData = [];
for(var k = 0; k<a[0].avg.length; k++) {
    lineData.push({
        avg: a[0].avg[k],
        model: a[0].model[k]
    });
}

console.log(lineGenerator(lineData));
```

And the final `console.log` returned this:

`d3-line.html:208 M0,370.3539823008849L20.952380952380953,357.07964601769913C41.904761904761905,343.80530973451323,83.80952380952381,317.2566371681416,125.71428571428571,330.5309734513274C167.61904761904762,343.80530973451323,209.52380952380952,396.9026548672566,251.42857142857142,385.28761061946904C293.3333333333333,373.6725663716814,335.23809523809524,297.34513274336285,377.1428571428571,NaNC419.04761904761904,NaN,460.9523809523809,NaN,502.85714285714283,NaNC544.7619047619047,NaN,586.6666666666666,NaN,628.5714285714286,NaNC670.4761904761905,NaN,712.3809523809523,NaN,733.3333333333334,NaNL754.2857142857142,NaN`

Finally, as you can see, there are some NaN in some `avg` attributes, I replaced them with a random number, replaced the line `.attr("d", function(d) { return lineGenerator(d.value); })` with `.attr("d", function(d) { return lineGenerator(lineData); })` and then we got a line:

[image: Result line]

Comment: Hey Guillermo, agree with you. Thought it would work too. Unfortunately not. Added a sample data and full code. Maybe that helps?

Comment: @Ashwin I just updated the answer, please check the edit.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot, Guillermo!!